# Devtools analyse function calls and variables post-factum

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I'm debugging a userscript, which is hard to debug, because the bug happens rarely and unpredictably (yet), and the function stack gets executed repeatedly (and the bug happens approximately once every 10-20 times). I cannot pause the devtools, otherwise the page will reload and the bug won't appear (so I cannot use breakpoints). Edit: even if I stop the page from reloading I still have to make user-input repeatedly and fast to cause the bug, so not possible to use breakpoints, because that would stop the bug from appearing.

One of the ways which I can think of is putting console.log in every function and logging variables and then searching through them to find where it went wrong. But it seems very tedious. In the performance section of devtools it's possible to record the process, and see the function calls, but it's impossible to see the variables.

Is there any way to go through the function call stack post-factum (maybe a tool other than devtools), seeing what the variables were equal to in every cycle? (And not only the current call stack, because it gets updated on every user input in my script). Or is console.logging my only option in this case?

I thought that "step out of the current function" option would work, but it seems to be unpredictable (it seemed to happen at least when there is setTimeout). And the function stack gets updated on every user input (and to capture this bug the user input sequence should be fast), so there is no way to go through the call stack either.

It would be perfect to have something like a call stack tree, which would show when a certain function was last called (and how many times during a certain period of time or since the page load), what was the position of this function in the tree of all functions, and the ability to go through this tree and search for all instances of calls to a specific function, and then the ability to see what the variables were equal to in every call.

There is a lot of code, but since it was requested, here is a link to the code inside a GitHub repository (it's a Chrome Extension, and the code where the bug happens is inside the objGA object [at the 6490's line of code]). And the bug happens somewhere between the 6600's line and the 6890's (the bug is that sometimes it doesn't move chess pieces on premoves). It's a Chrome Extension to move chess pieces with a keyboard and a mouse. 
https://github.com/Sentero-esp12/Lichess-Keyboard-WebRequest-/blob/master/Extension/code.js

Edit:
Luckily I was able to reproduce it in a slow pace with breakpoints (was able to find the exact moment when the bug appeared). So it turned out I was using `Math.round` instead of `Math.floor` trying to extract the first digit from a double digit number. Since only some numbers were >= *5, the bug appeared only occasionally and I couldn't notice the cause.

Comment: Shouldn't a userscript be able to stop the page from reloading? With a concrete example of the code, it might be possible for potential answerers to perform debugging too - it'd really help to be able to see what exactly's going on

Comment: Even if I stop the page from reloading I still have to make user-input repeatedly and fast to cause the bug, and then once I see the bug I could bind a key press to `debugger` but it would still be late, because new user-inputs would be made already (it's mousemove mostly). And my code is 700 lines and I don't know where the bug happens, maybe in one of several functions, which are around 200-300 lines of code... But I could post it, if it can help

Comment: Personally I'd go with `console.log`. You can also log the stack if you do `console.log(new Error().stack)`. It may take some time to analize, but it's reliable and fast to implement.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, I added the link to the code in the answer (it's a Chrome Extension)